# How to identify what apps are using internet?

Tags: macos, networking, internet

I have slow internet connection, when I watch online TV I'm trying to close those apps and processes on my Mac that use internet.

Besides the intuitive way (close skype, browser tabs, dropbox, etc) how to identify what apps are using internet?

Answer (score 0):

In Mavericks, `Activity Monitor.app` has a <kbd>Network</kbd> tab.  Its sortable columns include <kbd>Sent Bytes</kbd>, <kbd>Rcvd Bytes</kbd>, <kbd>Sent Packets</kbd>,  <kbd>Recvd Packets</kbd>, along with essentials like <kbd>Process Name</kbd>, <kbd>User Name</kbd>, and <kbd>PID</kbd>(process ID number).

In the default view mode `All Processes`, it's a bit difficult to tell, especially since there doesn't seem to be a delta mode, only a cumulative mode what processes are actively using the network.

To reduce the list to just active processes, select, under the `View` menu: `Active Processes`.

As I did so while writing this, doing so trimmed my process list from 3 or 4 pages of items, to just 10 lines.  Then I could easily see that only Safari Web Content was using the network, as I wrote this.  The top sender or receiver process can be identified by clicking on the column heading once or twice to resort the listing.